# What is the function of Boeing C-17 Globemaster III in the Indian Air Force?

Tags: military, indian-air-force, boeing-c-17

Why does India need [Boeing C-17 Globemaster III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_C-17_Globemaster_III)s?

What purpose do they serve in the Indian Military?

Comment: Is there somewhere some rule that one should downvote questions that are simple or easy to answer? Because I'm trying to find a reason for the downvotes and I can't. It's a legitimate question, in my opinion, even if a bit simple.

Comment: @DigitalDracula, the reason you can see in the edit history. Deletion of a sentence is giving this question up votes.

Comment: I find it incredibly hard to understand that the purpose of a transport aircraft would not be self-evident.

Comment: It’s a transport aircraft. It’s self-explanatory.

Comment: @Jpe61 It's not the **only** transport aircraft in the world.

Comment: @Jpe61, there were no Globemasters in the Indian inventory before 2009.

Comment: Question **specifically** asks "*What is the function of Boeing C-17 Globemaster III in the Indian Air Force*", not what is it's function compared to other transport aircraft in IAF inventory, or why C-17 was selected over some other acft.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The C-17 serves the same purpose in the Indian military as it does in other armed forces: it provides large-scale airlift.

India is a large country that has long borders with unfriendly neighbors, so it has a [requirement](https://www.defenseindustrydaily.com/c-17s-for-india-05924/) to move troops and supplies quickly to any hotspots.

> "The Indian military needs to do three things: augment its ability to quickly lift larger numbers of troops as it views possible threats on its border with China; strengthen its presence on the Pakistani border; and fight terrorism and low-intensity warfare", said a senior Defence Ministry official. "India needs to triple its lift capacity", said the official.

India spent on the order of $5B buying these aircraft, it's unlikely they'd pay that much for aircraft they don't need.

Comment: In addition, India has almost 7000 troops deployed worldwide on UN peacekeeping missions, these airplanes help transport and supply them.

Comment: there were no Globemasters in the Indian inventory before 2009.